# C socket recieves data then does not send it

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

i have created a simple socket connection which sends a request to a node.js app and receives some random data and then sends back the data but it sends and receives the data correctly but does not send back the random data

```
char *httpbody;
struct addrinfo hints, *result;
const char *host = "localhost";
char user[512] = "test@gmail.com";
char pass[512] = "test";
char headers[512];
srand(time(NULL));

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if (getaddrinfo(host, "3000", &hints, &result) != 0) {
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    perror("Could not resolve hostname.");
    exit(1);
}

int newsocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, 0);
if (newsocket == -1) {
    perror("Could not create socket.");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(newsocket);
    exit(1);
}

if (connect(newsocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    perror("Could not connect.");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(newsocket);
    exit(1);
}

sprintf(headers, "GET /auth?user=%s&pass=%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "User-Agent: Device\r\n"
        "Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
        "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n", user, pass);

if ((send(newsocket, headers, strlen(headers), 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Could not send data.");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(newsocket);
    exit(1);
}

char response[51201] = "";
recv(newsocket, response, 51200, 0);
response[strlen(response)] = '\0';

httpbody = strstr(response, "\r\n\r\n");
if (httpbody) {
    httpbody += 8;
}

int data = rand() % 255 + 1;

sprintf(headers, "GET /add_data?user=%s&data=%i&"
        "uid=%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "User-Agent: Device\r\n"
        "Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
        "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n", user, data, httpbody);

if ((send(newsocket, headers, strlen(headers), 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Could not send data.");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(newsocket);
    exit(1);
}

printf("done");

freeaddrinfo(result);
close(newsocket);
```

when i remove the revc request it works fine and it does not show any errors and i am completely lost

Comment: **Turn on all compiler warnings.** You have bugs in your code that you will find if you compile with warnings turned on.

Comment: response[strlen(response)] = '\0' does precisely nothing. The null is already there where strlen() tells you it is.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - i have enabled all the warnings and errors still no luck

Comment: @paxdiablo's deleted answer is correct. You have told the server to close the connection after sending the response, so it has done that. There are other problems with this code. You are ignoring the result returned by recv() for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check this lines of code:

```
recv(newsocket, response, 51200, 0);
response[strlen(response)] = '\0';`
```

recv doesn't return null-terminated data, so you cannot use strlen for determine size of data.
You must use return value of recv instead:

```
int data_size = recv(newsocket, response, 51200, 0);
```

Comment: And if it *did* return null-terminated data the second line would still be completely redundant. x[strlen(x)] is already null, for any x, by definition.

Comment: ok sorry i did missed that out how ever i made two new socket connections one will send and recieve random data and the other one will send the random data and i still have the same problem and the connection: close header it not the reason for the closed connection after recieve as i think

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP connection ends each time when you specify "Connection: close" in HTTP 1.1, thus the socket is not valid after you finish reading the response from the server.

Possible solutions are:

- Remove "Connection: close" header from the first request
- Connect() to the server again after you recv() the response